# VBA Vlookup Crashing

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

My VBA Vlookup code is crashing Excel and takes forever to execute. I need the VBA code and not the formula in the cell.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Call lookup
End Sub
Sub lookup()
    Dim srchres As Variant
    Dim srch As Variant
    Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Customer")
    Set sh4 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Invoice")

    On Error Resume Next
    srchres = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(sh4.Range("A11:C11"), _
        sh1.Range("B2:H99999"), 5, False)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If (IsEmpty(srchres)) Then
      sh4.Range("A12") = CVErr(xlErrNA) 
    Else
      sh4.Range("A12:C12").Value = srchres
    End If    
    On Error Resume Next
    srch = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(sh4.Range("A11:C11"), _
        sh1.Range("B2:H99999"), 6, False)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If (IsEmpty(srch)) Then
      sh4.Range("A13:C13") = CVErr(xlErrNA) 
    Else
      sh4.Range("A13:C13").Value = srch
    End If
End Sub
```

ThisWorkbook's code for creating a drop-down list

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim MySheets As Variant
    Dim srchres As Variant
    Dim srch As Variant
    Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Customer")
    Set sh4 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Invoice")
    MySheets = Array("sh1", "sh4") 

    If IsNumeric(Application.match(Sh.Name, MySheets, 0)) Then
        If Target.Address = "'sh4'!$A$11" Then
            sh4.Range("A2:A9999").Cells(sh4.Range("A2:A9999").Rows.Count + 1, 1) = Target
        End If
    End If    
End Sub
```

Comment: @BigBen - That does actually work.  I would have expected you'd need to use Evaluate to get back an array.

Comment: Try dropping the `WorksheetFunction` part

Comment: Interesting that even with the `WorksheetFunction` there is no error if one of the input values is not matched (or even if none of them are matched)...   Just two lookups should not take "forever" though.

Comment: Welp I definitely stand corrected, you can use a multi-cell range as the first argument. Unsure why Excel takes forever or crashes.

Comment: @BigBen I get the answer when I call it through the Worksheet_Change, but when I click on each cell, Excel crashes

Comment: What other code do you have in the sheet code module?

Comment: @BigBen I have code in ThisWorkbook for the drop-down list in sh4.Range("A11")

Comment: Which worksheet contains the `Worksheet Change` code? You probably need to disable events in parts of your code(s). Your last procedure definition (`ThisWorkbook`) should be `Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)`, where the address will never be `"'sh4'!$A$11"`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Thank you, I changed ```vb Worksheet_Change ``` in Invoice Sheet to the ```vb Worksheet_SelectionChange ``` and now it works